# uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\min(\frac{1}{xn!},xn!)$ in $(0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

i need to find out whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\min(\frac{1}{xn!},xn!)$ converges uniformly in $(0,\infty)$

I came to a conclusion that for evey $\epsilon>0$ I can find $N$ big enough so that $xn!>\frac{1}{xn!}$, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\min(\frac{1}{xn!},xn!)$ converges iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{xn!}$ , but i cant use the M test, because of the x in the denominator...
I cant also use Dini's theorem, as I didn't find a way to prove that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\min(\frac{1}{xn!},xn!)$ is continuous.

thank you for helping!

Comment: Deal with $[0,1]$ and $[1,\infty[$.

Comment: @EDX what for?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ since the sequence $\left(\min\left(\frac{1}{xn!},xn!\right)\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does not even converge uniformly to $0.$

Indeed, for all $N\in\Bbb N,$
$$\min\left(\frac1{xN!},xN!\right)=1\text{ for }x=\frac1{N!}.$$